# How to create 3 box with different sizes?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to create 3 boxes ,one big box and two small one next to it.Inside every boxes I have images .the problem is that the two small boxes are not responsive on any devices , it is working perfectly on desktop .I am really lost and can not find it out where I'm doing wrong and i'm working on since yesterday.

```css
.fashion_look img {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s, -webkit-transform 0.5s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s, transform 0.5s;
}

.main-container .block-container .fashion_look .content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  left: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 35px;
}

.main-container .block-container {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.main-container .widget-static-block {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.main-container .block-container .banner_top,
.main-container .block-container .new_shoes,
.main-container .block-container .fashion_look {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.main-container .block-container .overlay {
  bottom: 0;
  height: auto;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0.1s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0.1s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0.1s;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0.1s;
  width: auto;
  z-index: 2;
}

.main-container .block-container .new_shoes .content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 0%;
  width: 60%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 35px;
}
```

```html
<div class="widget widget-static-block">
  <div class="block-container">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <div class="fashion_look">
        <div class="overlay">&nbsp;</div>
        <a href="https://www.acureorganics.com/skin.html"><img src="#></a><br>
        <div class="content">
          <h3>&nbsp;</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
          <div class="new_shoes">
            <div class="overlay">&nbsp;</div>
            <img src="#">
            <div class="content">&nbsp;</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
          <div class="overlay">&nbsp;</div>
          <div class="banner_top">
            <a href="https://www.acureorganics.com/body.html"><img src="#"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="banner_top">
            <div class="content">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="content">&nbsp;</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with these boxes? Are they meant to be inline together, or are the two smaller ones supposed to be stacked on top of each other, but next to the larger box?

Comment: @Jhecht Thank you for taking your time to answer my question,Yes i want the two smaller ones to be stacked on top of each other, but next to the larger box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Using just Bootstrap 4's utilities

I was unsure where you expected the side section to show up on mobile, so here it shows up below the main section. Please note that the bg-colors were added only to make it clear what each section looked like.

```css
body, html{
  height:100%;
  }
  
  
  .container-fluid,
  .container-fluid .row{
    height:100%;}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-8 bg-primary text-white">
      <h2>Main Column</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
      <div class="row px-md-3">
        <div class="col-12 mb-md-3 bg-dark text-white">
          Top Secret
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 bg-warning">
          Bottom Secret
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you would like to see another implementation using some more custom CSS (or perhaps a grid setup) please let me know.

Comment: Thank you Jhecht people like you making the world beautiful :)
but the only problem right now i have is that if i do not put body, html{height:100%;} my boxes are very small ,how can i fix that

Comment: Without knowing where the element sits in the page it's hard to say. Really you need to make the parent container + the main row element have a height of whatever you need.

Comment: I want it in the middle of my page . how can i do that can you give me an example plz

Comment: What do you mean by "in the middle of my page"? Are there items above this particular section? Is this in a jumbotron/hero? Without knowing more about the layout, it's effectively a guessing game on my side.

Comment: @marie I'm more than willing to help you, but I do need some clarification.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that your images in the two small boxes are not scaling properly and don't fit on the same row when the screen is smaller.

If I add this CSS it works:

```
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Take a look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/smulvihill/kje4b79u/9/).

Comment: Thank you Steve :) but i tried this but only the images are getting smaller , i want them like go under each other in smaller devices .